# Swift 1.2 - Why isn't my UIPickerView displaying my data?

Tags: ios, mysql, asynchronous, download, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView which I load with data I download from a MySQL database.  The data downloads and fills an array, and then I use that array as the source of data for my pickerView through the delegate methods.

My issue is, everything works fine, except that the pickerView doesn't visibly fill for a good 20 seconds after the array has been filled.  I have tried running all sorts of `self.view.LayoutIfNeeded()` and the like, and have plenty of `pickerView.reloadAllComponents()` but it still refuses to load visibly.  However, if the user taps on the pickerView, or changes it value (even though it is visibly empty), the data suddenly appears.  I have tried programmatically selecting each row to try and force it to display, but that hasn't worked.

Here is my code to download the data (which is run on `viewDidLoad`):

```
func RetreiveStaff() {
    SetProgramMode()

    self.aUsers = [User]()
    self.pkvUser.reloadAllComponents()

    if self.booCurrentDataVersion == true {

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.website.com.au/retrievestaff.php")!
        let task:NSURLSessionDataTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data:NSData!, response:NSURLResponse!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let dataArray:[AnyObject] = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as! [AnyObject]
                for data in dataArray {
                    let dictionary:[String:String] = data as! [String:String]
                    if dictionary["StaffID"] != nil {

                        var newUser:User = User()
                        newUser.name = dictionary["LastName"]! + ", " + dictionary["FirstName"]!
                        newUser.id = dictionary["StaffID"]!.toInt()!
                        self.aUsers.append(newUser)

                        self.pkvUser.reloadAllComponents()
                        self.booDownloadedUsers = true
                    } else {
                        let actionSheet:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Users Downloaded", message: "Please ensure a user has been entered in Access and then restart the app.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        let firstAlertAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                            (alertAction:UIAlertAction!) in
                        })
                        actionSheet.addAction(firstAlertAction)
                        self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    self.pkvUser.reloadAllComponents()
                }
                println("\(self.aUsers.count) Staff Downloaded")
                self.pkvUser.reloadAllComponents()
                self.view.setNeedsLayout()
            } else {
                let actionSheet:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Connection Error", message: "\(strAppName) was unable to load data.  Check you are connected to the internet and restart the app.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                let firstAlertAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {
                    (alertAction:UIAlertAction!) in
                })
                actionSheet.addAction(firstAlertAction)
                self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })

        task.resume()

    }
}
```

Here are my pickerView delegate methods:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return self.aUsers[row].name
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if count(self.aUsers) > 0 {
        strSelectedUser = self.aUsers[row]
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.aUsers.count
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

where `aUsers` is an array of custom 'User' objects that I created.

What do I need to do to get the view to refresh/reload/display the data because I know the data is there.  I also understand that I am downloading it asynchronously and that can cause issues like this, but the data downloads almost instantly, and I don't understand why the view won't keep up.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you always have to update the UI in main threads, so once you have loaded the data (after you for loop I think) when you want to call the `reloadAllComponents()` you have to do it like below.

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.pkvUser.reloadAllComponents()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped and the data is now displaying instantaneously which is fantastic!  After I load the data, I programmatically select a row in the pkv, and when I do this, it only displays the entries above it (i.e., if I wanted to select number 3 out of 5, it would only display 1, 2 and 3).  Do you know what might be causing this?